# How can I set defaults for Moose attributes?

Tags: attributes, moose, defaults

It appears that Moose 'has' attribute requires the option 'is'.
It goes gaga if I omit it.

Practically every number or string attribute I declare will be 'rw'.

How can I set a default for 'is' so I don't have to write it every time?

I checked out Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native, but if it tells me how to do that, I'm too stupid to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the MooseX::HasDefaults module.

It gives you two options, either set the default to 'ro' or to 'rw':

```
use Moose;
use MooseX::HasDefaults::RW;

has 'thing' => (
  isa  => 'Str'
);
```

The above code creates an attribute 'thing' which is 'rw' by default.